# How to split String with multiple Separator at run time

Tags: java, string, split

I need to write a Java code which can split required String based on the Separator that we will pass. The number of separator can change too. 
 Example:

```
new StringSplit("\.").split("foo.bar#baz")
output = {foo, bar#baz}
new StringSplit("\.", "\#").split("foo.bar#baz")
output = {foo, bar, baz}
```

In constructor i am handle the number separator, but i am facing problem while designing the **split** method. Please help me on the same.

Comment: Could you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: What is `StringSplit`!

Comment: @BishnuPrasad How is this question related to `Selenium`? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, If I can understand your logic you need something like this :

```
public static String[] split(String input, String... delimiters) {
    String regex = Arrays.toString(delimiters).replace(", ", "");
    return input.split(regex);
}
```

You can call your method like so :

```
String input = "foo.bar#baz";
String[] result = split(input, "\\.", "#");
```

Outputs

```
[foo, bar, baz]
```

---

Details :

This method will take the string you want to split and the varargs of delimiters.
the [`String::split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method in Java use regex so you can create a regex by the delimiters I Just use a simple trick which is `Arrays.toString(delimiters)` this will return the string format of an varargs for example `[\., #]` the just replace the `,` to get a class of delimiters `[\.#]`

Comment: Hey...The above solution works fine...but how i can split if the separator it self a comma. For example,                                                                                        String input = "foo.bar#baz,eat"  and split(input, "\\.", "#", "\\,")                                   3rd separator is comma(,)

Comment: @Bishnu Prasad the comma in java is not special character so dont escape it like you do with the dot just use split(input, "\\.", "#", ",")